# Configuring Hibernate for HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am getting the following error to the simplest query:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: <table_name> is not mapped [<query_string>]
```

In `hibernate.cfg.xml` I have the property;

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

`ThreadLocalSessionContext` is in `org.hibernate.context.internal` of `Hibernate 4.x-hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar`.

Everything else on Hibernate is working fine. However, 
i'm not being able to run a query.

What am i missing?

Thanks for help.

//=========================

EDIT:

`<table_name>` is defined as an entity in `hibernate.cfg.xml` and **everything** but HQL-- including the updates on `<table_name>` are working with no errors.

Comment: What you're missing is the error message, and the fact that HQL never uses table names and column names, but always entity names and field/property names. <table_name> is not mapepd means that there is no entity known to Hibernate that is named <table_name>. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: Why don't you post the actual code and the actual query?

Comment: Can you provide us with the query you are trying to execute before having that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities which comes to my mind

1. The name you are referring in your HQL is not an Entity. For e.g.,

   HQL is "Select testEntity from TestEntity testEntity" , however there is no entity      class named TestEntity defined

or

1. You have defined TestEntity but it is not managed. You say that other operation in entity are working,  it looks like you are probably using wrong name in your HQL.
   However if you want to be sure that the Entity is managed, you can enable the Hibernate debug logging and you should see information like below in which you can see the list of managed classes.

   ```
   01:09:40,322 DEBUG HibernatePersistenceProvider:110 - Checking persistence-unit [name=persistence-unit_test, explicit-provider=org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence] against incoming persistence unit name [persistence-unit_demo]
   01:09:40,322 DEBUG ProviderChecker:106 - Persistence-unit [persistence-unit_demo] requested PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]
   01:09:40,322 DEBUG LogHelper:117 - PersistenceUnitInfo [
       name: persistence-unit_demo
       persistence provider classname: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
       classloader: null
       excludeUnlistedClasses: false
       JTA datasource: null
       Non JTA datasource: null
       Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
       PU root URL: file:/E:/Test/target/classes/
       Shared Cache Mode: null
       Validation Mode: null
       Jar files URLs []
       Managed classes names [
           com.test.model.TestEntity

       Mapping files names []
       Properties [
           hibernate.c3p0.timeout: 100
           hibernate.connection.autocommit: false
           hibernate.connection.driver_class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
           hibernate.c3p0.max_statements: 0
           hibernate.c3p0.max_size: 50
           hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
           hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period: 100
           hibernate.c3p0.min_size: 5
           hibernate.connection.username: XXXX
           hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
           hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment: 5
           hibernate.connection.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
           hibernate.connection.password: XXXX
           hibernate.show_sql: true
           hibernate.connection.provider_class: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
   01:09:40,337 DEBUG IntegratorServiceImpl:63 - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
   01:09:40,353 DEBUG IntegratorServiceImpl:63 - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The error should mostly come from the `query itself`. you should try and make sure the name the `Entity` your are executing a request on is exactly like the name of the `class` not like the name of the `SQL table` associated to it.